# Bash loop through multiple directories

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

I do not know if this topic was reached or not bot couldn't find anything related.

I have a bash script and I want to do a for loop through multiple directories with the mention that I want to output in a log file only `*.txt/files` but the loop to don't go on sub-directories.

My desire is to use the directories in variables. I am  using an array where I wrote the directories I search for them.
When the script is ran the output is what is in array, not what is in the directories...

This is how my code look now, what should I do?:

```
#!/bin/bash

l=/home/Files/Test1/
j=/home/Files/Test2/
k=/home/Files/Test3/

arr=("$l" "$j" "$k")

for i in "${arr[*]}"
do
  echo "$i"  >> test
done
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `I want to do a for loop through multiple directories` You say that, yet I think you meant that you want to loop through _files in multiple directories_, not through directories.

Comment: yes, sorry for confusion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `find` the actual files.

```
find "${arr[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -type f >> test
```

You *could* depend on shell filename expansion:

```
for dir in "${arr[@]}" # properly handle spaces in array values
do
      for file in "$dir"/*; do
          # check for empty dir
          if [ -f "$file" ]; then
              # Use printf, in case file is named ex. `-e`
              printf "%s\n" "$file"
          fi
      done
# don't reopen the file on each loop, just open it once
done >> test
```

but that's a lot more, just `find` it.